# How to FillLeft and copying values only

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I would like to `FillLeft` and only paste values but I'm not sure how to write it!

I assume I should use `xlPasteValues` but I'm not clear where to write it in below code

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Columns("B:D").Hidden = True
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:E13").FillLeft
```

I would like the contents of Column E to be pasted as Values in Column A

Comment: Are you looking for `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A13").Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E1:E13").Value`?

Comment: Do you mean by `FillLeft` : `xlToLeft`